# Filling column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
          Col1          Col2
1          NaN         Someval1
2           Y          Someval2
3           N          Someval3
4          NaN           NaN
5          NaN         Someval4
```

I would like to fill NaN with the conditons:

```
If Col1 has NaN and Col2 has a Someval1 that is in list 1 then fillna with Y
If Col1 has NaN and Col2 has a Someval4 that is in list 2 then fillna with N
If Col1 has NaN and Col2 has a NaN that is in list 2 then fillna with N
```

Any suggestions ? (don't know if it's possible)

Many Thanks !

Comment: NaN that is in list 1? :)

Comment: list 2, thanks for the verification ill edit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), for conditions [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
L1 = ['Someval1','Someval8']
L2 = ['Someval4','Someval9', np.nan]
m1 = df['Col1'].isnull()
m2 = df['Col2'].isin(L1)
m3 = df['Col2'].isin(L2)

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(m1 & m2, 'Y')
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(m1 & m3, 'N')

print (df)
  Col1      Col2
1    Y  Someval1
2    Y  Someval2
3    N  Someval3
4    N       NaN
5    N  Someval4
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Col1'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'Y',
             np.where(m1 & m3, 'N', df['Col1']))

print (df)
  Col1      Col2
1    Y  Someval1
2    Y  Someval2
3    N  Someval3
4    N       NaN
5    N  Someval4
```

---

Another solution with one condition and `fillna`:

```
L1 = ['Someval1','Someval8']
L2 = ['Someval4','Someval9', np.nan]

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(df['Col2'].isin(L1), df['Col1'].fillna('Y'))
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(df['Col2'].isin(L2), df['Col1'].fillna('N'))
print (df)
  Col1      Col2
1    Y  Someval1
2    Y  Someval2
3    N  Someval3
4    N       NaN
5    N  Someval4
```

Answer (score 0):

here's [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) solution

```
df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin(['Someval1']), 'Col1'] = 'Y'
df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin(['Someval4']), 'Col1'] = 'N'
df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin([np.nan]), :] = 'N'
```

full script:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Col1          Col2
1          NaN         Someval1
2           Y          Someval2
3           N          Someval3
4          NaN           NaN
5          NaN         Someval4
"""), sep="\s+")

df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin(['Someval1']), 'Col1'] = 'Y'
df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin(['Someval4']), 'Col1'] = 'N'
df.loc[df.Col1.isnull() & df.Col2.isin([np.nan]), :] = 'N'

df

  Col1      Col2
1    Y  Someval1
2    Y  Someval2
3    N  Someval3
4    N         N
5    N  Someval4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.Col1[(df['Col1'].isnull())&(df['Col2']=='Someval1')] = 'Y'
df.Col1[(df['Col1'].isnull())&(df['Col2']=='Someval4')] = 'N'
df.Col1[(df['Col1'].isnull())&(df['Col2'].isnull())] = 'N'
```

Comment: second line ovverrides 'Someval4' in 5th row; second and third line doesn't support fillna to Col1 in 4th and 5th rows

Comment: @tworec I think the `list 2` refers to `column 2`, I'll change it.